# How to draw other shapes or lines in `rot-js` canvas?

Tags: javascript

I'm using `rot-js` to draw a grid with hexagons and want to add triangles and other shapes to the `canvas`. I've tried acting on `display.getContainer()` but that's not working. What needs to be done to get this to work?

Setting `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor"`, I'm able to see the objects being drawn (but the colors are all wrong).

Setting `ctx.globalAlpha = .8` also allows everything to be visible to an extent so I'm thinking this has something to do with layers.

If I work directly on an existing `canvas` element, drawing works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell for sure since you didn't provide anything about what you are actually doing, but given the description, I'll guess you are not waiting for the next frame before doing your own drawings over the ones made by the library.

The library stacks all its rendering operations in a `requestAnimationFrame` callback, so if you do it before, your drawings will be covered by the lib's ones.

To workaround this, simply wrap your own drawing operations in a `requestAnimationFrame` callback, it will get stacked after the ones of the lib, and will get drawn on top.

```js
const display = new ROT.Display();       
const canvas = display.getContainer();
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// async calls
display.draw(5,  4, "@");
display.draw(15, 4, "%", "#0f0");
display.draw(25, 4, "#", "#f00", "#009");
// end async calls


// this will get covered
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(20,20,40,40);

// wait next frame
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  ctx.fillRect(120,20,40,40);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rot-js"></script>
```